# TFS 2012 Web Access Save Query Results Disabled

Tags: tfs

I've installed TFS 2012 and have a problem with the Save Results button in the web access forms where query results are displayed. It is greyed out in all cases, even running on the server where TFS is installed.

Anyone know how to enable this button? The refresh, open, and both link buttons on this toolbar work fine, but the Save Results button is greyed out and cannot be clicked.

Thanks for any assistance.

Oh, also, if anyone knows how to make the row background color alternate in the results grid I'd be forever in your debt!

Answer (score 5):

Silly me, I assumed "Save Results" would save the results of the query, but it just saves the changes in any work items returned by the query. To export these results, select any item in the grid (then control+a to select all items) and cut/paste into excel

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+a (in chrome) selects the entire page.

What worked for me was to select the top row, then hold shift, and select the bottom row. Then ctrl+c, a dialog opens up, then another ctrl+c, and then pasting into Excel (select "ok" on the prompt).

Worked like a champ.